# after bind data to gridview it will not show on table in grid view

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

I am creating Windows Application in c#. In that Application i want to join two tables and show it as a single table in grid view. After bind datasource to gridview, grid view will
not shown on form....Here is My code

```
private void btCheckSupplier_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string checkSupplier = tbProdcutId.Text;
        try
        {
            DataSet checkSupplierDataSet = new DataSet();
            DataSet n = dal.SupplierDetail(checkSupplierDataSet);

            BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
            bindingSource.DataSource = n.DefaultViewManager;
            if (dataGridView2.Rows.Count == 0)
            {

                dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dataGridView2.DataSource = bindingSource;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    static string conn = @"Data Source=MyComputer-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";

    public string CheckSupplier(string checkSupplier)//string checkSupplier
    {
        try
        {
            string checkString = "select [Products].ProductID,[Products].ProductName,[Suppliers].SupplierID,[Suppliers].CompanyName,[Suppliers].ContactName,[Suppliers].ContactTitle,[Suppliers].Address,[Suppliers].City,[Suppliers].Region,[Suppliers].PostalCode,[Suppliers].Country,[Suppliers].Phone,[Suppliers].Fax,[Suppliers].HomePage from [Products] Inner Join [Suppliers] On [Products].SupplierID = [Suppliers].SupplierID Where [Products].ProductID ='" + checkSupplier + "'";
            SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(checkString, connect);
            connect.Open();
            sqlcom.Connection = connect;
            sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();
            return checkString;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    public DataSet SupplierDetail(DataSet supplierDetail)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(conn);
            Class2 checkObj = new Class2();
            connect.Open();               
            SqlCommand sqlCom = connect.CreateCommand();
            sqlCom.CommandText =checkObj.CheckSupplier(checkString);here checkString is called From CheckSupplier method.
            SqlDataAdapter sqlAd = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sqlAd.SelectCommand=sqlCom;                
            sqlAd.Fill(supplierDetail);
            connect.Close();
            return supplierDetail;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: something to try is to debug your application and set a debug point on CheckString (in the CheckSupplier method) and make sure that the query you are generating is actually returning any results by copying the value of CheckString and running it in sql directly, this way you will know without a doubt that the query that your application is running works and the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @jgok222 Ya rite i found where is the error...Thank you for your reply